# Flickity slider with custom css per carousel-cell

Tags: flickity

I want to set custom height (and possible other things) the the flickity 'carousel-cells' INDIVIDUALLY. I can see it is calculated somehow with with javascript by the [flickity package](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) itself.

How could I overwrite this, to create something like this (with the smaller inactive slide)?

[image] .

I have tried to give the carousel-cells a height of 300px, and the active carousel (who has a class `is-selected`) a height of 500px. That did not work.

```
.carousel-cell {
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #8C8;
}

.is-selected{
  height: 500px !important;
}
```

[A simple codepen to get you started if you like.](https://codepen.io/nclsvh/pen/OmoKdg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work off the `asNavFor` sample until you get to a view like in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/oluwafemisule/pen/YVJzLd)

Comment: Hmm, that seems like the way to go. I'll give it a try! Thanks

Comment: How would you tackle the problem from the sliders? Slider 1 must show slide n, while slider 2 must show slide n+1 (also on change).